# jquery/ I want to make my code more clear by using for-loop

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie in this service. While I do coding, I have a question. But I can't find any page to solve my problem...

I want to below code to more clear by using a for-loop.
What can I do for this?

```
$('.special1').on("click",'.chkbutton1',function() {
    $('.special1').toggleClass('effect-oscar effect-oscar-second');
});
$('.special2').on("click",'.chkbutton2',function() {
    $('.special2').toggleClass('effect-oscar effect-oscar-second');
});
$('.special3').on("click",'.chkbutton3',function() {
    $('.special3').toggleClass('effect-oscar effect-oscar-second');
});

<<omitted>>

$('.special11').on("click",'.chkbutton11',function() {
    $('.special11').toggleClass('effect-oscar effect-oscar-second');
});

$('.special12').on("click",'.chkbutton12',function() {
    $('.special12').toggleClass('effect-oscar effect-oscar-second');
});*/
```

Comment: This seems more suited for CodeReview.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use for loop. You can simply use like this:

```
$('[class^="chkbutton"]').on('click',function(){
   $(this).parent() //not sure if .special.. is parent, select the correct element
    .toggleClass('effect-oscar effect-oscar-second');
});
```

I think `.parents('[class^="special"]')` would be suitable.

---

Or, you can use [delegateTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) like this:

```
$('[class^="special"]').on("click",'[class^="chkbutton"]',function(e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget).toggleClass('effect-oscar effect-oscar-second');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use for loop here but you can do it in following way:

```
$('[class^=special]').on("click",'class^=chkbutton',function() {
    var classList = $(this).attr("class"); //get all the classes associated with button; one of then will be starting with chkbutton 
    var classArray = classList.split(" ");
    $.each( classArray, function( i, val ) {
        if(val.indexOf("chkbutton") == 0)
        {
            var requiredClass = val;
            var number = requiredClass.replace("chkbutton", ""); //grab the number
            $('.special'+number).toggleClass('effect-oscar effect-oscar-second');
        }
    }
});
```

**Note:** I couldn't able to test above code but i have used valid jquery selectors so quite sure that it will work as per expectations.